# Gracefully migrate from SSRS2014/IE to SSRS2016/Edge

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, aspx-user-control

I have a chicken-egg-problem when upgrading from SSRS2014 to SSRS2016.

- I cannot move to the new reportviewer because I still have users on
  IE. The new report viewer cannot print nicely on Internet Explorer:
  if you click print, you can download a pdf and THEN print it.
  Due to the large amount of reports we print, this is no feasable option.
- I cannot migrate away from Internet Explorer because of the old report
  viewer: The ActiveX print control only works in Internet Explorer.

So I want to migrate to the new report server, yet show the reports through the old viewer for IE-users. So my test web server has both the new and the old reporting component. If the client uses Internet Explorer, I serve the old one. Otherwise, they get the new one.

In my test environment, reports from SSRS 2016 are rendered correctly by the old reporting control. (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms version 11.0.0.0) However, when I try to print, the client displays a dialog box "Unable to load client print control"

On my server, an exception is thrown:

```
The report server could not find the internal resource '2015.130.1601.05rsclientprint.cab'. (rsInternalResourceNotFoundError) 

[ReportServerException: The report server could not find the internal resource '2015.130.1601.05rsclientprint.cab'. (rsInternalResourceNotFoundError)]
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.WritePrintCab(ClientArchitecture arch, Stream stream) +797
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.WritePrintCab(ClientArchitecture arch, Stream stream) +75
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +304
```

I know there is a new reporting control, making the ActiveX print control obsolete. However, I'd like to prevent a big bang implementation. Printing with the old control only works on Internet Explorer, so all users use IE. Printing with the new control DOESN'T work with IE.

(If 100+ users print 50+ reports a day, having to download a pdf and print that is a BIG difference.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/enable-and-disable-client-side-printing-for-reporting-services says: 
"**Previous versions of Reporting Services used an ActiveX control that required downloading to the client computer from the report server. If you upgrade your report server to SQL Server 2016, the print control is not removed from the report server or client computers.**"

This suggests that ActiveX printing is also possible with the new server, probably through the old Report viewer control. If that works, I can put the new control next to the old one, and gradually migrate my users to a modern browser.

Did anybody get this to work without restarting and installing SQL Server 2014, and upgrading?

Comment: If you have a 2016 report server why not upgrade the reportviewer? It's a lot better than the old stuff and not to bad to upgrade.

Comment: @Snowlockk Eventually, I want to upgrade the reportviewer. However, the new reportviewer offers a lousy print experience under IE: you have to download a pdf open it, then print it. At 5000 prints a day, that's not a viable option right now.

Comment: Do the users need real-time reports and do they supply any parameters? Had to solve this issue with previous versions and it was a nightmare. I hope your reports port over ok.

Comment: @realbart, also, have you tried installing report viewer redistributable package (separate from SSRS)? Looking at the missing cab version, I would take a guess that report viewer 2015 may help solve the issue. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Comment: I don't think you can use the old reportviewer if you think about it, it hasn't been updated to support the RDL format changes. I think the part you read about it not removing the print control is purely a note to point out it won't be removed. I guess there could be a scenario where you need the print components available for an older reporting services instance while having a 2016 one as well.

Comment: It would probably be better to look if you can get the PDF to automatically print in Internet Explorer. There are javascript examples of printing PDF's automatically but i'm not sure on browser support an integrating it with the SSRS output. It would probably mean adding your own print button.

Comment: @realbart couple of other thoughts - clearly, the server fails to silently distribute ActiveX because it's not on the server. Hence, my previous suggestion stands - install both x86 and x64 RSPrintClient distros. If real-time reporting is not required and input params are static, create subscriptions to dump PDF reports to a shared folder and expose it through an IIS virtual directory with folder browsing enabled. I think it would be just the same as accessing the report and clicking the export button. There's also an option of creating a small custom site that connect to the reporting web svc

Comment: @Dennis: We're using SSRS for things like invoices. How do I install the 2014 RSPrintClient distros on 2016?

Comment: @realbart I would assume invoices can be produced using subscriptions and dumped into a shared folder you can access through the browser. Distros - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496 download x86 and x64 and install them on the Windows server hosting SSRS. This articles are a bit old but look beyond the SSRS version number as they describe the problem. Of course, you don't want to distribute printing components manually. http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/client-side-printing-silent-deployment-of-rsclientPrint.aspx

Comment: @realbart and one more: http://daddyr.blogspot.com/2012/11/silently-deploy-ssrs-printing.html

Comment: @Dennis thanks for your pointers. Currently, the activex print component is distibuted through a group policy, so everybody can print using Internet Explorer.

Comment: @realbart I am sure that's the case and I may be wrong, but... it seems to me it's the server that's missing the required cab. Anyway, I would try that first because the workaround is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate SSRS Reports from 2014 to 2016. Simply follow below steps:

1. Backup and restore original databases
2. Backup encryption key
3. Install Ssrs 2016 on new server with managed service account.
4. Restore databases and remove server key entry from key table in the report database.
5. Configure Ssrs 2016 to look at new restored databases on same new instance.
6. Restore keys from backup.

Or visit this link :https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2692/migrating-sql-reporting-services-to-a-new-server-by-moving-the-reporting-services-databases/

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I've done the upgrade itself a few times now. My question is more about solving the chicken-egg-problem of how to migrate away from Internet Explorer. However, your answer inspired me to formulate my original question better.